# Thrift generate python dependencies

Tags: thrift

I have 2 thrift definition files within the same namespace

**file1.thrift**

```
namespace some_name
some types
```

**file2.thrift**

```
namespace some_name
include "file1.thrift"
some types ....
```

when doing

```
thrift --gen py -r -out folder file2.thrift
```

I expect to get the types defined in file1.thrift generated in the python code.
But that is not the case...
What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

The Apache Thrift compiler overwrites existing files without a warning. Because you use the same namespace, certain files like `ttypes.py` and `constants.py` are overwritten when the next IDL file is processed.

### Solution

- Always put declarations belonging to one namespace into one Thrift IDL file
- Use different namespaces for different Thrift IDL files

Comment: I see... Thank you very much for this. It would be certainly an improvement if the compiler could aggregate the sources in the same file.

Comment: I think, the biggest single source of misunderstanding ist the overloaden `include` keyword. With Thrift IDL `include` could be better described as a "**uses**" relationship. It is by no means a textual inclusion, as one could think.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add a corresponding sub-namespace to each file.

For example:

**file1.thrift**

```
namespace py some_name.file1

...
```

**file2.thrift**

```
namespace py some_name.file2

...
```

Then it shouldn't overwrite the files. I would hope this gets fixed for python since it works well for other languages without this hack.